# Find Element by xpath in python using selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How I can find these by xpath.

```
<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin_2224175();"> <span>&nbsp;</span><div class="btn3">Like</div></a>
```

and

```
<button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 PageLikeButton _4jy4 _517h _9c6" data-profileid="776072132447222" data-ownerid="u_jsonp_2_t" id="u_jsonp_2_u" type="submit"><i class="_3-8_ img sp_WMP_MjDZgeq sx_96dbd2"></i>Like</button>
```

Comment: Hi Mark - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Supposed the `elements` have those class names being unique in the tree, you can use `find_element_by_xpath`.

For **a**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="single_like_button btn3-wrap"]')
```

And the **button**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//button[@class="_42ft _4jy0 PageLikeButton _4jy4 _517h _9c6"]')
```

Source: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html
Of course you can also use the tree path to get the element, but that cannot be answered due to your incomplete source.

Hope this helps.